# bit.ly links in wordpress twitter status updates leads to 404

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, bit.ly, twitter-feed

All the twitter status updates on the wordpress sidebar have bit.ly links. When I click on them, I get the 404 page because instead of going bit.ly/uniquenumber it tries to go www.domain.com/blog/"http://bit.ly/uniquenumber/" with www.domain.com/blog being the homepage for the wordpress blog.

Is there an easy way to stop it from adding www.domain.com/blog and quotes and taking us to the actual link?

Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code :

```
/* These prefixes and suffixes will display before and after the entire block of tweets. */  
        $prefix = ""; // Prefix - some text you want displayed before all your tweets.  
        $suffix = ""; // Suffix - some text you want displayed after all your tweets.  
        $tweetprefix = ""; // Tweet Prefix - some text you want displayed before each tweet.  
        $tweetsuffix = "<br \><br \>"; // Tweet Suffix - some text you want displayed after each tweet.  

        $feed = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:" . $username . "&rpp=1" . $limit;  

        function parse_feed($feed, $prefix, $tweetprefix, $tweetsuffix, $suffix) {  

        $feed = str_replace("&lt;", "<", $feed);  
        $feed = str_replace("&gt;", ">", $feed);  
        $clean = explode("<content type=\"html\">", $feed);  

        $amount = count($clean) - 1;  

        echo $prefix;  

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $amount; $i++) {  
        echo $tweetsuffix;
        $cleaner = explode("</content>", $clean[$i]);  
        echo $tweetprefix;  
        echo $cleaner[0]; echo $suffix; echo $tweetsuffix;  ?>

        <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/side.png" alt="A line dividing the twitter updates and the open courses listing">
        <?php 
        }    
        echo $suffix;  
        }  

        $twitterFeed = file_get_contents($feed);  
        parse_feed($twitterFeed, $prefix, $tweetprefix, $tweetsuffix, $suffix);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're link is going to `www.domain.com/blog/"http://bit.ly/uniquenumber/"`, it's because there's an extra " at the start of the bitly url. If a url doesn't start with a defined protocol (http, https, ftp etc) the browser will append it to the current folder.

Comment: Do you have tips on how to fix it?

Comment: The url in the tweet status update does contain http:// at the beginning of the link.

Comment: The quote mark might not be *in* the url, but somewhere leading up to that point in your code you are outputting it.

Answer (score 0):

without seeing the code and judging by your comment, it looks like the links are malformed on whatever plug-in is generating the links, probably not quoted right, which is why they are showing up in the URL.